# Why do GET requests to my Google Apps Script's Web App intermittently timeout?

Tags: web, google-apps-script, get, timeout

Periodically, no response comes back from my GAS web app, despite making identical calls via GET. Instead, the calling application reports a timeout condition after waiting 15+ seconds*.

I have used hurl.it (with 'Follow Redirects' set) -- an excellent testing tool! -- as well as Twilio messaging service to invoke the same URL, parameters, values, etc. and found that the response times out, as if the intended Google Apps Script code never ran.

The timeouts are intermittent, with no pattern as to time of day, requesting URL, payload (GET parameters), etc. Furthermore, the underlying GAS code works flawlessly at all other times.

Sample GET request:
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw5LddY3SIv-dD6U_1ibAy7cGog5WjmHyDDUSyBq0G2k9gZ3rkI/exec?MessageSid=1234&From=+8081234567&Body=newman

Expected XML response:
`<Response><Sms>Timothy has sent you ...</Sms></Response>`

*NOTE: The underlying GAS code, whose performance does not seem to factor into my dilemma, typically executes in 0.125 seconds when responses do come through.

While troubleshooting, I have double- and triple-checked the "obvious stuff" such as making sure to deploy the latest code as Web App..., ensuring that the code itself contains a doGet() function, that all services have been authorized, user permissions are set to "Anybody (even anonymous)", and so forth.

My suspicion at this point (call it my wit's end) is that Google's servers simply do not react at random times, and this is causing a serious backlog in my work. Any insights much appreciated! I've thoroughly checked this and other forums for similar complaints, to no avail.

THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Answer (score 1):

FINAL (valid?) "SOLUTION"

I also implemented `lock.tryLock(10000)` (see GAS Documentation) at the beginning of my script, so that Trigger-based and GET-requested instances of my code would not trip over each other. Likewise, I added `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` at the end of any scripts/functions that alter spreadsheet data, to prevent collisions.

Ironically, adding the BetterLog library to my Project appears to have introduced its *own* Timeout issue, namely with the use of `getLastRow()` in its code. Careful observation of View > Execution Transcript (thankfully, BetterLog also logs its own activity in the native Logger!) revealed that instances of `getLastRow()` were taking 10-20 seconds *each* to execute! I consider this a genuine flaw within GAS and have therefore submitted a thorough Bug Report on Google's issue tracker.

Here's a sample line to demonstrate the issue (which remains intermittent):
[16-06-11 07:11:13:980 CDT] Sheet.getLastRow() [20.141 seconds]

SEMI-FINAL (almost valid?) "SOLUTION"

About the only remaining trick in my bag was to see whether any code collisions were happening behind the scenes. Ultimately, after disabling an existing project Trigger (set to run every minute), the timeouts problem vanished! This makes me reluctant to restart that (very necessary) Trigger, but scientific method demands that I do so in order to tell whether the timeouts problem returns.

NOTE: I am, of course, led to wonder WHY perfectly functioning codebase would be so easily tripped up by two (independent) subroutines running in parallel? My suspicion is that, since both utilize the same functions and access the same underlying Spreadsheet, there is risk of an (unannounced) *locking* violation. Why this would in turn manifest as Timeouts (instead of Error messages) is beyond me, but suffice to say my enhanced logging efforts (see notes below...) show clearly that runtime escalates from 0.3 seconds to about 60 seconds(!!) when it occurs.

ORIGINAL (invalid) "SOLUTION"

The underlying problem *appeared* to be connected to the use of GAS's native Logger function. Removing instances of `Logger.log()` from my code led almost immediately to improved timing, to the point where the app responds to every single GET request for a long stretch of time.

Accordingly, I implemented Peter Herrmann's most excellent helper library `BetterLog` (see https://github.com/peterherrmann/BetterLog) to serve my logging needs, with activity being recorded on a new sheet (appropriately named 'Logs') within the connected Spreadsheet in Google Drive.

For the following two hours, Web App responsiveness remained at 100% ... however, the original problem returned with a vengeance later the same afternoon, whereupon responsiveness dropped to 0%.

Will update further (or edit this Answer) should any other insights arise!